# How to update a value using in firebase realtime database?

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

So I am using Cloud Functions at the moment. What I am doing is this:

```
export const onMessageCreate = functions.database.ref('/Users/{user}/{message}/{text}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const data = snapshot.val()
      const changedData: string = change(byteData.text)
      return snapshot.ref.update({id: compressedByteData}) //This is the problem
  })
```

The `change(input: string): string` is a custom function of mine that just replaces every occurrence of the word happy birthday with a birthday cake emoji. Thing is however that in my reference which looks like this: `"/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}"` I want to update the value of text. Since, however, I don't know what `{text}` is I can't store it in the correct location. Does anyone have some suggestions?

The `change()` function is:

```
function change(data:string):string {
       return data.replace(/\bhappy-birthday\b/g, '')
}
```

Here is the Firebase node picture:
[Firebase Node Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BwKwF.png)

So I want to change the 01, 02, 03 with my Cloud Functions (the values don't matter).

Visual Representation of what I want to do:
[Visual Representation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bIeF2.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**New Update following your comments:**

If I understand correctly your last comments, this should do the trick:

```
export const onMessageCreate = functions.database.ref('/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      const changedData: string = change(byteData.text);

      const user = context.params.user;
      const messageGroup = context.params.messageGroup;

      return admin.database().ref(`/Users/${user}/master/${messageGroup}/content`).update({4f3f: changedData}); 

  })
```

**Update following your comments:**

Sorry but it not 100% clear what you want to update.

If you want "change the value of `/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}` when (you) create the value at `/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}`" with the value of `changedData`, just do as follows:

```
export const onMessageCreate = functions.database.ref('/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}').onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();
      const changedData: string = change(byteData.text);
      return snapshot.ref.update({message: changedData}); 
  })
```

---

Within your Cloud Function you will be able to get the path values by doing

```
const user = context.params.user;
const message = context.params.message;
```

and then build the desired node reference.

---

As you can read in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/database-events):

> You can specify a path component as a wildcard by surrounding it with curly brackets; `ref('foo/{bar}')` matches any child of `/foo`. **The
>   values of these wildcard path components are available within the
>   EventContext.params object of your function**. In this example, the
>   value is available as event.params.bar.

Comment: Actually it is not 100% clear which value you want to change . Could you update your question with an extract of your database (or at least a print screen of it's structure) and indicate what you exactly want to modify?

Comment: So, you want to change value of "/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}" when you create a value under "/Users/{user}/{message}/{text}". Is that right?

Comment: No I want to change the value of  "/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}" when I create the value at  "/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}". The {message} is the problem. My first question was something else, because my company does not allow full disclosure you know...

Comment: Ok so you may adapt the path where you trigger the Cloud Function in your question because for the moment the paths are different.

Comment: `Error: Reference.update failed: First argument  must be an object containing the children to replace`: is the error it gives in the logs when I try the first method

Comment: Basically, if I create a node with this inside of it: "Happy Birthday, Matilda" it would replace the happy birthday with the birthday cake emoji. That isn't the problem, because even if I pass a "Hello World!" in the `update()` it still gives the error.

Comment: See the update: there was an error in y answer. It has to be be `return snapshot.ref.update({message: changedData});` instead of `return snapshot.ref.update({changedData);`

Comment: no that doesn't work because the message is a wildcard and it depends on the message id. what it does now is just add another node inside the message, like this: `message: [2, 302, ]` Any suggestions?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "the message is a wildcard and it depends on the message id". If it means that the value of `message` is an array and that you want to change only one element of the array, you will have to **rebuild the entire array** with the value that you want to change (at the desired array index) and update the record with this new array.

Comment: What I mean is that the {message} in the ref is a wildcard. I want to set the value of the {message}. But putting message: "hello" doesn't work. Because what it does is create a object under the {message} with a key message. I need to change the val of the {message} (we don't know that)

Comment: Ok, thinks are a bit more clear! But you said (see your comment above) that "I want to change the value of "/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}" when I create the value at "/Users/{user}/master/{messageGroup}/content/{message}"." So I have the feeling that you know the value of message, don't you? If not how do you get this value of 4df3ff... ? You have to know it in order to modify this exact message.

Comment: Yeah I know the value  of message. But now I want to modify the value of the message.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand!... If you want to modify  the value of the message, you should know with which value you want to modify it. Or you want to use a random value??

Comment: You may try with `return snapshot.ref.update({message.4df3ff4f-3: changedData});` but this is just a guess since I don't really understand what you mean.

Comment: You don't understand... When I modify message(which is a random value) I can't do {4f3f: changedData}. What that would do is create another object inside the message with key 4f3f. And 4f3f is just a random value so its not guaranteed that it would be the same every time. I want to change 4f3f and make 4f3f: newVal and not 4f3f->message:newVal  Hope you understand.